# 'origin' must be supplied&unambiguous format

Tags: r, csv, transformation, xts

I am a beginner in R. I have the following problem - I want to load a CSV file into R and then convert it into a XTS object. However, after the operation I get an error. First, a small snippet of the data:

```
a=read.csv('/Users/..../Desktop/SYNEKTIK.csv',h=T)
head(a)
  Name     Date      Open  High   Low Close Volume
1 SYNEKTIK 20110809  5.76  8.23  5.76  8.23  28062
2 SYNEKTIK 20110810  9.78  9.78  8.10  8.13   9882
3 SYNEKTIK 20110811  9.00  9.00  9.00  9.00   2978
4 SYNEKTIK 20110812  9.70  9.70  8.90  9.60   5748
5 SYNEKTIK 20110816  9.70 11.00  9.70 11.00  23100
6 SYNEKTIK 20110818 10.90 11.00 10.90 10.90    319
```

The following does not work:

```
w=xts(a[,-1],order.by=as.POSIXct(a[,1]))
```

As it produces the following error:

> error'as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...)':
>     character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Another try that did not work:

```
a=a[,-1]
head(a)
  Date      Open  High   Low Close Volume
1 20110809  5.76  8.23  5.76  8.23  28062
2 20110810  9.78  9.78  8.10  8.13   9882
3 20110811  9.00  9.00  9.00  9.00   2978
4 20110812  9.70  9.70  8.90  9.60   5748
5 20110816  9.70 11.00  9.70 11.00  23100
6 20110818 10.90 11.00 10.90 10.90    319


w=xts(a[,-1],order.by=as.POSIXct(a[,1]))
```

> error 'as.POSIXct.numeric(a[, 1])':'origin' must be supplied

Finally, when I saved the date in the following format: yyyy -mm - dd Everything turned out right, and I could convert into an XTS object, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this will help:

```
w <- xts(a[,c(-1,-2)],order.by=as.Date(as.character(a[,2]),"%Y%m%d"))
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, everything works fine. Problem solved. Very thanks again. Greetings